# Issue with Visual Studio 2022 and GitHub: CodeDom Provider Error in ASP.NET Web Forms Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, github, webforms, visual-studio-2022

My friend and I are using Visual Studio 2022 with GitHub for collaborating on an ASP.NET Web Forms application. When one of us clones the repository, everything is downloaded correctly. However, when the person who cloned the project tries to run it, we encounter the following error:

> Parser Error Message: The CodeDom provider type
> "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider,
> Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***************" could not be located.

We've attempted to create new projects, but we encounter the same problem. We've verified that both of us are using the same versions of Visual Studio and related components, and we've checked for updates. However, we're still unable to resolve this issue.

Additionally, at some point, I unloaded the project and attempted to edit the project file by right-clicking on the project name and selecting the "Edit" option. Unfortunately, when I click on the "Edit" option, nothing happens.

We shared the project by clicking on Git in the Visual Studio bar and selecting "Create a new repository" and then sharing it with my friend as a collaborator using the GitHub website.

We've been trying to fix this for the past few hours without success. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After you clone the project, then I suggest you go to Project->Manage NuGet packages.

This option:

[image]

You then should on the tab have an option to "update" packages.

I would try updating them all, see if that works.

[image]